# UploadedFileReferenceConverter alternative needed for typo3 10

Tags: image, upload, typo3

phpStorm gives me the following comment:

Class 'UploadedFileReferenceConverter' is marked as @internal, the following code to handle an image upload should work for typo3 vs. , but I need a alternative for typo3 vs. 10

I read this, but I don't know how to use and where to place this code. Any help appreciated

New in version 10.2: Starting with version 10.2 a file can be retrieved directly by its filename from the folder::

```
$file = $folder->getFile(“filename.ext”);
```

```
  /**
    * action show
    *
    * @param \Covisiomedia\PdfGenerator\Domain\Model\Pdfgenerator $pdfgenerator
    * @return string|object|null|void
    */
   public function showAction(\Covisiomedia\PdfGenerator\Domain\Model\Pdfgenerator $pdfgenerator)
   {
       $this->view->assign('pdfgenerator', $pdfgenerator);
   }

   /**
    * Set TypeConverter configuration for image upload
    *
    * @param string
    */
   protected function setTypeConverterConfigurationForImageUpload($argumentName): void
   {


       \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\Container\Container::class)
           ->registerImplementation(
               \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference::class,
               \Helhum\UploadExample\Domain\Model\FileReference::class
           );


       $uploadConfiguration = [
           UploadedFileReferenceConverter::CONFIGURATION_UPLOAD_FOLDER =>
               '1:/profilbild/',
       ];
       /** @var PropertyMappingConfiguration $newExampleConfiguration */
       $propertyMappingConfiguration = $this->arguments[$argumentName]->getPropertyMappingConfiguration();
       $propertyMappingConfiguration->forProperty('image')
           ->setTypeConverterOptions(
               UploadedFileReferenceConverter::class,
               $uploadConfiguration
           );
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your own UploadedFileReferenceConverter class with the content from https://github.com/helhum/upload_example/blob/master/Classes/Property/TypeConverter/UploadedFileReferenceConverter.php in Classes/Property/TypeConverter/ and use this

```php
$propertyMappingConfiguration->forProperty('image')
           ->setTypeConverterOptions(
               \Vendor\Extension\Property\TypeConverter\UploadedFileReferenceConverter::class,
               $uploadConfiguration
           );
```